# Django 2 Images from STATIC_URL is not loading in Css

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I'm working on a Django(2.1.7) project in which I need to load some images in css file.
Here's what I have so far:

**From `settings.py`:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'), ]
```

I have a directory in my main project folder named as `assets` and also have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and then I have mentioned some images in css as:

```
background: url('/assets/images/demo.png') center no-repeat;
```

The image is available in the `images` folder but not displaying in the template.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Did you specify `{% load static %}` at the beginning of  your template?

Comment: the path you specify in your css is **relative to your css file path**. So this would only work if your css file is in a directory that contains the 'assets' directory.

Comment: Assuming you also have a /assets/css/ directory where your css file is located, the link to your image should be "../images/demo.png".

Comment: Hi @RajanSharma, I'm inside the `css` file where `{% load static %}` doesn't work and template is working.

Comment: Hi @dirkgroten I have `images` folder inside my `assets` folder`.

Comment: You can inline background on the html element using:

    {% load static %}
    <div style="background: url('{% static "assets/images/example.jpg" %}')></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you specify in your css is **relative to your css file path**. So this url would only work if your css file is in a directory that contains the *assets* directory.

The question is where is your css file. Assuming it's in a */assets/css* folder (inside `assets`), your url should be:

```
background: url('../images/demo.png') center no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below snippet to your `urls.py` file

```
# <----------- rest of the code----------->
urlpatterns += static('/assets/', document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(
    settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
)
```

Comment: This is not needed since the OP is using 'django.contrib.staticfiles' so in debug=True mode, runserver automatically finds the static files in the various /static directories of the apps and inside the /assets directory (since he added that to STATICFILES_DIRS). And even then, this should definitely be removed in production settings (so wrap in `if settings.DEBUG == True:`). And finally, it only serves the files if they're in `STATIC_ROOT` so you'd have to run `collectstatic` on your development machine all the time a change is made to static files.